# How can I execute something after a new window has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I need to close a new window after it fully loads.  I have:

```
my_window=window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=500, height=400, top=10, left=10");
```

I've tried:

```
my_window.onload = my_window.close();
```

and

```
my_window.addEventListener('load', my_window.close(), true);
```

Neither wait for my_window to finish loading before closing (it closes pretty much immediately).

Secondary question, can I add a timeout to go ahead and close the new window in case the page stalls and for some reason never fully loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your window is on the same domain, you can use this:

```
 my_window.onload = function() {my_window.close();};
```

or this:

```
my_window.addEventListener('load', function() {my_window.close();}, true);
```

You don't use parens after the function name when passing a plain function reference.  Using the parens as you were doing causes the function to get executed immediately.

I also added anonymous functions so the `my_window` context can be preserved until function execution time.

If your window is not on the same domain, then you probably have issues with [same origin protections](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript&ei=D1VOUrb0FsewjAKW2IDICQ&usg=AFQjCNGJ1-YtDsCj5BCtdLq1wRuON-if6A&sig2=xkzjL45icaShWdqzp9czkw&bvm=bv.53537100,d.cGE) that keep you from accessing the javascript of the other window.

Comment: Wouldn't that close `window`? Assigning `= my_window.close;` would assign `close` without a _context_ to the `onload` so if called it is called in the default context (`window`). Or is this a special case?

Comment: @t.niese - yes, I modified my code to be sure the right context is used.

Comment: Will this wait for the window to fully load then close before executing any more script below the line `my_window.onload = function() {my_window.close();};`?  I want to open another new window but it has to be after the first one has fully loaded then closed.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to the server to test this at the moment since they have to all be on the same domain.

Comment: @JackHillard - no, it won't wait.  Javascript in the current window will continue to run.  There is no ability to "block and wait" in javascript other than a few simple functions like `alert()`.  `my_window.close()` will be called some time in the future when `my_window` finishes loading.