# Close a window after it has finished loading from window.open with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Please forgive me if this has been answered before but I've searched and searched and haven't been able to find a solution to my problem.

I'm using Greasemonkey in Firefox and Tampermonkey in Chrome to automatically open a link on a webpage I visit frequently. Below is the javascript code:

```
// ==/UserScript==
var link = document.querySelector('[href*="/cgi/admin/user/ssh_login/"]');
var url = link.getAttribute('href');
var sshlink = "https://"+document.domain+url;
//alert(sshlink);
var openWindow = window.open(sshlink,"ssh","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
window.blur();
setTimeout(function(){openWindow.close();},2000);
```

This opens the link in a new popup and closes it after 2000ms. What I'd actually prefer is to have the `openWindow.close();` happen *after* the popup's window.open is done loading. I've tried [both of these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19174082/5309708) and neither have worked.

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone know what I can do differently to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Why not just use an Ajax call and not deal with a pop up window at all?

Comment: That would be great. Unfortunately, I'm not very knowledgeable on scripting. Would you be able to show me the right Ajax code to do what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a pop up window to make a GET request to the same server. Just make an Ajax call.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", sshlink);
oReq.send();
```

No need to worry about pop up blockers and if the window loaded. The code above will make a GET request to the url and it does nothing with the response that comes back. [Basic tutorial on Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: So I just used that code that you gave me above and now it's not loading the link at all. Not sure what I did wrong. `// ==/UserScript==
var link = document.querySelector('[href*="/cgi/admin/user/ssh_login/"]');
var url = link.getAttribute('href');
var sshlink = "https://"+document.domain+url;
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", sshlink);
oReq.send();`

Comment: You are not going to see it load anything unless you look at the developer console and watch the request.

Comment: I'm not even seeing the request loading in the console though.